# How can I place the results from NgbTypeahead into a DIV container, rather than a dynamic dropdown?

Tags: ng-bootstrap

I'm using NgbTypeahead, and it's working properly. But instead of creating a dynamic popup window with the results, I'd like to show the results in a list in DIV.

I *think* I'm supposed to use the **container** property to do this, but I've this:

```
<input #quickSearch id="typeahead-template" type="text" class="form-control popup-search"
       [ngbTypeahead]="searchWithTemplate" [resultTemplate]="searchResultsTemplate"
       (selectItem)="searchResultSelected($event)" [container]="resultsContainer"
       [inputFormatter]="formatter" [placement]="'bottom-left'"
       [placeholder]="isSearchInitialized ? 'Search for...' : 'Please wait... initializing quick search...'"
       [disabled]="!isSearchInitialized"
       style="width:100%">
```

and it doesn't work. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm stating the obvious but the docs say it only supports body

> A selector specifying the element the tooltip should be appended to. Currently only supports "body".